# Postpone class template to its constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am afraid what I am looking for is impossible. It might need change of my design. I am looking for postponing a class template to its constructor. Here is the example:

The following code is working with no problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T1,class T2>
T1 product(T1 t1,T2 t2)
{
    return (T1)(t1*t2);
}

int main()
{
    double t1=5.5;
    int t2=4;
    cout<<t1<<" x "<<t2<<" = "<<product(t1,t2)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, if I want to wrap the function `product` inside a class:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T1,class T2>
class A
{
public:
    T1 num1;
    T2 num2;

    template<class T1,class T2>
    A(T1 t1,T2 t2)
    {
        num1=t1;
        num2=t2;
    }

    T1 product()
    {
        return (T1)(num1*num2);
    }

    T1 division()
    {
        return (T1)(num1/num2);
    }   
};

int main()
{
    double t1=5.5;
    int t2=4;

    // i need types here, this will not compile because 
    // i would need to explicitly state A<double, int> here.
    class A a(t1,t2);
    cout<<t1<<" x "<<t2<<" = "<<a.product(t1,t2)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code does not compile. Obviously because it is looking for `<double,int>` as the template of the class. Fixing the compiler error is easy and not my concern.

My concern is that now, I feel I have lost an advantage! In previous code, I could call the function with no worry about the type. I gave arguments to the function. Now I have to give the parameter types to the class first. I cannot have a class defined from automatic detecting type of t1 and t2. Is there any way to postpone the class template to its constructor?

Maybe you believe giving type of  to class template is very easy and no worth arguing! But imagine a very complex case.

Comment: Looks at what the standard does, i.e. `make_shared`, `make_pair`, `make_unique`

Comment: Why is `A`'s constructor a template? The types of the data members are determined by the class' template arguments, so I see no benefit in having the constructor be a template too. Also, please use [constructor initialization lists](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html) to initialize data members.

Comment: @Praetorian Left it there to show what i need. Imagine it does not exist. The main question remains the same.

Comment: @akira Are you kidding?! Please do not *fix* the code when the question is about the errors it produces in its current form.

Comment: the question is NOT about compile errors. it's about the need for `A<double, int> a(1.0, 1);`. that was the point of my change since the syntax and compile error are clouding what OP wants to know.

Comment: @barej Mat answered your question in the first comment, create a `make_A` function that will perform type deduction and return an instance of `A`. You can then use `auto a = make_A(t1, t2);`

Comment: @Praetorian: yep, that's the answer: make-function + use of c++11-auto. in that one line i put the comments before. the only line that will now refuse to compile and actually highlights the only real problem OP has :)

Comment: @akira, you may post it as an answer.

Comment: @Praetorian I am still reading documents about make_* to see how I should fix it.

Comment: @barej: your last code-edit now makes me scroll to see the problem. there is so much text i just don't want to grok. obviously i like my compact version better since it makes it easier to get to the actual problem, but since you have a different oppinion i won't touch it again. just saying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You create a creator function which returns "the right thing(tm)":

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto make_A(T1 n1, T2 n2)->A<T1, T2> {
    return A<T1, T2>(n1, n2);
}
```

And use it later on like this:

```
auto a = make_A(t1, t2);
```

And that's it. But be aware: `auto` is a pretty "newish" keyword, you might run into troubles if you run into old compilers. Before refactoring your huge project you should check the lowest compiler you have to support.

Further information:

- Scott Meyers "Type Deduction and Why You Care" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQxj20X-tIU
- Mike Action "Data-Oriented Design and C++" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rX0ItVEVjHc ... this talk is to question your need for "classes because of why not?!"

Comment: as far as auto is C++11 compatible it is fine. My concern is that is using make_A generates extra copy of the class too? does it need to be passed by reference?

Comment: what do you mean: `t1` and `t2`? or what gets returned by `make_A()`?

Comment: being returned by make_A. I am not in that expert level to recognize by myself. just wondering if two objects are being created from type A in memory or only one?

Comment: i think there is only 1 object created due to RVO?

Comment: @MarsonMao: just for reference: RVO - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization "is a compiler optimization technique that involves eliminating the temporary object created to hold a function's return value."

Comment: @barej: it might be compiled away (see the RVO reference), it might not. you can be sure only if you consult the manual of your compiler. or you provide the storage space yourself but then you can't use the auto-keyword. your sample-code does obviously not show the real situation you are in, so noone can really give advise to your overall problems. maybe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rX0ItVEVjHc give you another perspective on "things".